# Set Variable to Empty Dict if None in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm looking to recreate this in a test suite:

```
if value is None:
    value = {}
```

I plan to be adding to the dictionary so the following does not work:

```
${default}=    Create_Dictionary
${value2}=    Set_Variable_If    ${value} is ${None}    ${default}
...    ${value}
```

When I add a key to `${value2}` it gets added to `${default}` (most likely due to how Python passes around references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Run Keyword If` to run a keyword to set a variable.  This can call `Create Dictionary` and create a new & unreferenced dictionary to set your variable.

```
${value}=  Run Keyword If  ${value} is ${None}  Create Dictionary
...  ELSE  Set Variable  ${value}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using robot framework 2.9 or greater you can use variables directly in python expressions by omitting the curly braces. If you have a robot variable named `${value}`, you can reference it as `$value` where robot is expecting a python expression (such as with the [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword).

For example:

```
${value2}=    evaluate    {} if $value is None else $value
```

Comment: hey @Bryan, I am also facing the similar problem, i.e.`[]! = None`
So, in such case, `${val}=      evaluate []` - would it be a good option? In a broader sense, is it advisable to use `evaluate`? Also, Can I use `create list` to create empty list?